# neon-animated-pages with embedded dom-repeat element

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

We are building a survey mechanism where we can have the user create their own set of questions, the type, etc. The users can show up a single element at a time. Or a group of questions. I use the neon-animated-pages to go from one singular question to another.

-- index.html --

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
   <section data-route="home">
     <test-survey surveyid="99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999" submissionid='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'}' ></test-survey>
   </section>

   <section data-route="users">
       <paper-material elevation="1">
       </paper-material>
   </section>

   <section data-route="user-info">
       <paper-material elevation="1">
       </paper-material>
   </section>

   <section data-route="contact">
       <paper-material elevation="1">
       </paper-material>
    </section>
</iron-pages>
```

--test-survey.html--

```
<div class="vertical layout">
  <div class="flex">
    <neon-animated-pages id="views" class="flex" selected="0" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
    <test-template items="{{survey.Questions}}" id="surveyquestions">
    </test-template>
  </neon-animated-pages>
    <paper-toast
      id="toast"
      text="Saved successfully.">
    </paper-toast>
   </div>
</div>
```

Since needing to be able to group questions together, we moved the following code to another file, stand alone so it can be called from a place where single questions are asked. Or from a place where it will take a list of questions as a group and show them within one section.

--test-template.html--

```
<template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="surveyquestions" items="{{items}}" sort="_sort">

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isFormat(item.Type, 'Single-Select')}}" >
           <question-singleselect question="{{item}}"></question-singleselect>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isFormat(item.Type,'Open-Ended')}}">
           <question-openended question="{{item}}"></question-openended>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="[[isFormat(item.Type,'Multi-Select')]]">
             <question-multiselect question="{{item}}"></question-multiselect>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="[[isFormat(item.Type,'Section')]]">
           <question-section question="{{item}}"></question-section>
        </template>

        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isFormat(item.Type,'Numerical')}}">
           <question-numerical question="{{item}}"></question-numerical>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

--test-chrome.html--

```
<template>
    <paper-card heading="{{question.Title}}" id="paper-card-{{question.Id}}">
       <div class="card-content {{question.Type}}">
           <div class="questionanswers">
              <content select=".questionanswers"></content>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="card-actions">
          <paper-button class="raised primary" on-tap="prevAction" id="prevButton_{{question.Id}}" hidden$="{{_hidePrev(question.Type)}}">Previous</paper-button>
          <paper-button class="raised primary" on-tap="nextAction" id="nextButton_{{question.Id}}" hidden$="{{_hideNext(question.Type)}}">Next</paper-button>
          <paper-button class="raised primary" on-tap="saveAction" id="saveButton_{{question.Id}}" hidden$="{{_hideSave(question.Type)}}">Submit</paper-button>
      </div>

    </paper-card>
</template>
```

Once I put the list of question-types into a separate form, it stopped working. It listed all the questions on one page, instead of navigating from one question to the next. It works if the section of test-template.html is back in the test-survey.html

Comment: I think we need more context (more than just code fragments) to figure out the problem. Can you post the code before/after you moved question types?

Comment: What is the best site to post all of the code? I tried jsfiddle, but I am thinking there is something somewhere where I don't have to break the code part so much.

Comment: Probably github.com

Comment: OK...so here it is...there are two files you can see the difference between them in the test-survey folder..the one that works as expected is test-survey2.html...where the neon-navigation works, and shows one question at a time....survey1.html is the one that doesn't work. Basically all the question types have been moved into test-template.html only.... please and thank you.  https://github.com/gpolito1970/surveytest/